# Не работает событие click в safari

Tags: javascript, html

Не могу понять. Во всех браузерах работает. А сафари игнорит выполнение события при клике по элементу

**html**:

```
<div class="show_block"></div>
```

**js**:

```
$(document).on('click','.show_block',function(e){
    alert('good');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В файл css добавьте

```
.show_block{
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

или как запасной вариант добавьте атрибут onclick к блоку

```
<div class="show_block" onclick=""></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо. Сработало!