# Не работает jQuerry код именно в Safari

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, safari

Подскажите почему данный код в Safari не работает? Версия **13.0.5**
В Chrome работает нормально.
Он должен открывать изображение на весь экран и затемнять фон при клике.

Скорее всего дело в JS

```
(function($){
  $(".merch-img").on('click', function(){
    var img = $(this);
    var src = img.attr('src');
    $(".view-section--content").append("<div class='popup'>"+
             "<div class='popup_bg'></div>"+
             "<img src='"+src+"' class='popup_img' />"+
             "</div>");
    $('.view-menu').css('z-index', '0');
    $('.view-header').hide();
    $(".popup").fadeIn(400);
    $(".popup_bg").click(function(){
      $(".popup").fadeOut(400);
      setTimeout(function() {
        $(".popup").remove();
        $('.view-menu').css('z-index', '20');
      }, 800);
      $('.view-header').show();
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Но возможно и со стилями что-то:

```
.popup {
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: none;
    text-align: center
}

.popup_bg {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%
}

.popup_img {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    max-height: 94%;
    max-width: 94%;
    margin: 1% 0 0 0
}
```

И [страница](http://shogun.com.ua/klubna-atributika), о которой идёт речь, если вдруг нужна кому-то:

Comment: "в Safari не работает" - ??

Comment: Сказали не работает, но проверить нет возможности, у меня винда.

Comment: @Sevastopol' открытие картинки в полный экран при нажатии

Comment: @Sevastopol' в браузере Safari не работает код, который представлен выше. Что именно - пытаюсь понять.

Comment: @Sevastopol', ну в принципе есть идея, но автор даже версию не указал.

Comment: @Qwertiy у вас есть возможность протестировать на Safari?

Comment: Во-первых, нет. Во-вторых https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5263/178988. В третьих, я уже перечислил.

Comment: @Sevastopol', по крайней мере у него на сайте тот же код без компиляции.

Comment: Увы на этом сайте не все такие опытные как Вы в js

Comment: @Sevastopol' там же написано для тех случаев, когда ответ решил вашу проблему... В данном случае этот ответ не несёт мне никакой  пользы, учитывая на сколько мало конкретики в нём. Я не `гуру` программирования.

Comment: @Sevastopol'  максимально доходчиво объяснил Вам уже можно было и понять, код весь приложил, который открывает картинку в полный экран в Хроме. Тот же самый код не выполняет свою функцию в другом браузере. В чем причина?

Comment: @Sevastopol'  onclick, append, и стили, которые я проверил, все они поддерживаются.

Comment: [Похожая проблема](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/888999/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5-click-%D0%B2-safari)

Answer (score 1):

Деструктуризация поддерживается в Сафари начиная с версии 11.1.
А шаблонные строки - с 11.
Стрелочные функции - с 10.

Вероятно, стоит от чего-то из этого отказаться.

Comment: Уточните, пожалуйста, где именно в коде происходит деструктуризация?

Comment: Эм.. Т. е. ты сам найти не можешь?

Comment: Скорее я не понимаю что означает деструктуризация

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Comment: Что-то всё равно не понятно где тут деструктуризация.

Comment: Тут: `$('.merch-img').click(({currentTarget})=>{`

Comment: Уточнил версию браузера саффари - 13.0.5, какие ещё могут быть идеи?